# Whats wrong with my javascript canvas code?

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas

I wrote this js canvas code. It works but it paints half of a canvas angularly. Can I do something to correct this code or I need to fully rewrite it. Is it right to put this code inside setup().  Thank you. 
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random

```
var side = 10;
var grassArr = [];
var matrix = [];



console.log(matrix)


function setup() {
    for(var y = 0; y<49; y++){
    matrix[y] = [];
    for(var x = 0; x<49; x++){
let arr = [0,1,2]
let r = random(arr)
matrix[x][y] = r
matrix.push(r)    
}
}


frameRate(5)
 createCanvas(49 * side, 49* side);
  background('#acacac');
}


function draw(){
        for (var y = 0; y < 49; y++) {
for (var x = 0; x < 49; x++) {
        if(matrix[y][x]== 0){
                fill('#acacac')
                rect(x * side, y * side, side, side);
            }
                if(matrix[y][x]== 1){
                fill('green')
                rect(x * side, y * side, side, side);
            }
            if(matrix[y][x]== 2){
                fill('yellow');
                  rect(x * side, y * side, side, side);

            }
        } 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a small error on the matrix construction. Here, corrected it for you.

```js
var side = 10;
var grassArr = [];
var matrix = [];

function setup() {
    for(var y = 0; y<49; y++){
        matrix[y] = [];
        for(var x = 0; x<49; x++){
            let arr = [0,1,2]
            let r = random(arr)
            matrix[y][x] = r;
        }
    }

    frameRate(5)
    createCanvas(49 * side, 49* side);
    background('#acacac');
}


function draw(){
    for (var y = 0; y < 49; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 49; x++) {
            if(matrix[y][x]== 0){
                fill('#acacac')
                rect(x * side, y * side, side, side);
            }
            if(matrix[y][x]== 1){
                fill('green')
                rect(x * side, y * side, side, side);
            }
            if(matrix[y][x]== 2){
                fill('yellow');
                rect(x * side, y * side, side, side);
            }
        } 
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You were inverting x and y variables in the matrix creation and calling .push again which generated lots of undefined places in the matrix.

If you want just call console.log(matrix) after matrix creation using your code version and you'll see lots of undefined values.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.